# How to replace gwt json with my own json implementation

Tags: json, gwt

**I need to find a method to work json implementation in my gwt-project  `com.google.gwt.json.client` package instead of json in GWT `com.google.gwt.json package`.**

In my GWT project I want to use json implementation written by myself and stored in a package in my project with same path as that of GWT json package.

Files inside this packages are `com.google.gwt.json.client` implemented by myself and keep in same package in my project, how to configure in project to use these packages instead of original.

Any suggestions regarding this will be appreciated.

Thanks to all..

**UPDATES:
For more clarification on what I am looking for: 
While parsing with JSONUtils in GWT, make parser to use JSONObject written in my project `com.google.gwt.json` package, insted of GWT-json in `com.google.gwt.json` package.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it is necessary to modify certain GWT core classes because either, you need to fix an issue, or you need to add a new feature to them.

To override any GWT implementation class, for instance `com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject`, you only have to copy and modify that class in your src folder with the same path: `src/main/java/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONObject.java` if you are using maven,  `src/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONObject.java` otherwise.

The only care you need is that your `src` folder is first in your classpath than the gwt sdk, with maven it is so by default. You should be aware as well that when you update the gwt version, perhaps you would need to update your implementations.

If the instances of the class you were trying to override, are created in GWT using the `GWT.create()` call, you could replace the class with your own implementation with a `<replace-with>` tag in your `.gwt.xml`. This technique is called [deferred-binding](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred). This is not the case since `JSONObject` is normally created with `new`.

Finally the <[super-source](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideOrganizingProjects)> tag can be used to override any class implementation in compile time. Although `super-source` is designed to override `jre` classes by `gwt` implementations, replacing gwt with other gwt implementations works. In this case you have to put your modified classes, with the same namespace structure, in the folder pointed by the `super-source` tag.

Comment: How can i assure that my source folder is first in my class path? I am not using maven.

Comment: What are you using, eclipse, ant?

Comment: So go to `Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export` and verify that your src is at the top

Comment: Is it possible to do it by specifying exclude tag in my_project.gwt.xml file?

Comment: I dont follow, what tag do you mean?. I have updated my answer explaining how to replace classes using deferred binding.

Comment: I got solved the problem with <super-source path=""/> tag, using it in my my projects gwt.xml files. Anyway thanks..